# Cannot edit alert message

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert, message

User can add own alert window messages on page load. It's almost working. The last problem is that when i edit the alert message, update the changes and refresh the page, there's no alert message. Code:

```
if(action === 'alert'){
            var parentDiv   = jQuery(this).parents('.dx-columns');

            jQuery('#dx-alert-content').val(parentDiv.find('.hidden').html());
            jQuery('#dx-alert-type').val(parentDiv.attr('data-alert'));
            jQuery('#dx-alert-ids').val(parentDiv.attr('data-alert-ids'));

            if(parentDiv.attr('data-alert')=='On Click'){

                jQuery('.dx-alert-ids-wrap').show();
            }

            if(parentDiv.attr('data-alert') == 'On Page Load') {

                jQuery(' .dx-alert-content').show();

            }
            if (action.action === 'edit') {
                var parent_div = $(this).pa
            }

            jQuery('#dx-alert').dialog({
                  width: 1200,
                  height: 350,
                  close: function( event, ui ) {
                      jQuery( this ).dialog( "destroy" );
                  },
                  buttons: {
                    'Save': function () {

                        var content = jQuery('#dx-alert-content').val();
                        parentDiv.attr('data-alert',jQuery('#dx-alert-type').val());
                        parentDiv.attr('data-alert-ids',jQuery('#dx-alert-ids').val());
                        content = jQuery(content).text().replace( 'script', '' );

                        var check   = parentDiv.find('.hidden').length;

                        if(!check) {
                            parentDiv.append('<div class="hidden">' + content + '</div>');
                        }
                        else{
                            parentDiv.find('.hidden').html(content);
                        }

                        jQuery(this).dialog('destroy');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: `"and refresh the page"` - What specific value in this code is being lost?  Where do you persist that value so that it would be retained after refreshing the page?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `html` instead of `val` here? `jQuery('#dx-alert-content').val(parentDiv.find('.hidden').html());` it's hard to help without the html

Comment: "refresh the page" i mean that i run the code and it should disply the alert + edited message, but no